# Julia - strange joinpath() behaviour

Tags: julia

This is supposed to prefix the given path:

```
date = Date(2016, 6, 3)
const FILEDATE_FORMAT = "YYYYmmdd"
const FILE_PATH_FORMAT = "/YYYY/mm/"

joinpath(
 "path-prefix",
  Dates.format(DateTime(date), FILE_PATH_FORMAT),
  Dates.format(DateTime(date), FILEDATE_FORMAT)
)
```

Expected: `"/path-prefix/2016/06/20160603"`

Actual:   `"/2016/06/20160603"`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, `/` is the root directory. Since your `FILE_PATH_FORMAT` begins with the character `/`, `joinpath` is interpreting this as the root directory, and, as per the behaviour of that function, everything that comes before it is omitted since the path is already absolute.

The solution is to just drop the leading `/` from `FILE_PATH_FORMAT`.

By the way, I need to use `yyyy`, not `YYYY` on my system. Not sure why `YYYY` works for you...